# Sketch the set of points represented by the following quadratic equation.

Tags: matrices

Sketch the set of points represented by the quadratic equation: $$\begin{pmatrix} x & y\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 1$$

I multiplied this out and got: $$x-2y=\pm 1$$

Is the solution just these two lines drawn on an $xy$ plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the solution just these two lines drawn on an $xy$ plane?

That's right, you would call this a [degenerate conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic).

Comment: I have since noticed that if I plot $x^2-4xy+4y^2 =1$ I get a different graph than $x-2y=\pm 1$. Which one is correct or which one is being asked for in the question?

Comment: @Derek Are you sure you get different plots? ([plot1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bx%5E2-4xy%2B4y%5E2+%3D1%7D) and [plot2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7Bx-2y%3D1,x-2y%3D-1%7D))

Comment: Oops , I had $y^2$ instead of $4y^2$. They are the same.

Comment: Alright, problem solved! :-)